# Set Camera Image Size

Tags: xcode, image, core-data, camera, photo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compress an Image taken by the camera in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889687/how-to-compress-an-image-taken-by-the-camera-in-iphone-sdk)

I have created a CameraViewController that captures images to a Transformable Attribute in Core Data.  When I take a picture and save it to the data store, the photo is saved at a very hight resolution.  I want to reduce the photo size that is saved on disk to a resolution of about 150x150 rather than the standard 1600x1600.

How can I do this so that I can improve performance.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the blog post http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/ and also one SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889687/how-to-compress-an-image-taken-by-the-camera-in-iphone-sdk . Hope that helps you.